# AVAudioPlayer not playing sound on some devices

Tags: ios

I am using AVAudioPlayer to play an audio file its working but on some device it does not play how do i solve my problem

```
if(_defaultSettings)
        {
            _soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ring" ofType:@"wav"];
            NSLog(@"ringTone Path%@",_soundFilePath);
            //    /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/
            _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:_soundFilePath ]error:nil];
            [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
            [_audioPlayer play];
            _audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1000);
        }



- (void)playSystemSound {
    NSLog(@"playSystemSound");
    // Create the URL for the source audio file. The URLForResource:withExtension: method is
    //    new in iOS 4.0.
    NSURL *tapSound   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"short_low_high"
                                                withExtension: @"wav"];

    if (!self._soundFileURLRef) {
    // Store the URL as a CFURLRef instance
    self._soundFileURLRef = (CFURLRef) [tapSound retain];

    // Create a system sound object representing the sound file.
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (_soundFileURLRef, &_soundFileObject);
    }

    // Play the sound
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (_soundFileObject);
     //    // to vibrate the device   // AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

}
```